# Ubuntu machine not starting up

Tags: 14.04, mount, startup, teamviewer

I tried to install Teamviewer in my ubuntu machine. I followed the steps mentioned in this link: http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-teamviewer-on-ubuntu-14-10.html for the command line installation.

I tried to mount it manually but still it didnt work.

I am not able to figure out what went wrong.

[Start Up screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbRmw.png)

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I getting the error "The disk drive for /mnt/usb-ZTE_USB_Storage_FFF1-0:0 is not ready yet or not present" on start up.

For the past 8 hours it is continuing to load :( :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to mount? I don't see any mouning instructions in that link

Comment: hi nick i didnt mount anything after giving sudo apt-get -f install.then my system behaved abnormally. I restarted and this error starting showing up

Comment: Do you have an external USB hard drive or something? Try unplugging it (just while your computer boots up) and see if that resolves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with Teamviewer. There is no mounting step in their command line installation tutorial :)

It looks like your Ubuntu is trying to mount an USB key that has been unplugged.

What you should do is start a **"live"** ubuntu session (via an USB key for example), as a mean to repair your Ubuntu installation.

Once that is up, open the disk where you have Ubuntu physically installed, and modify the contents of `/etc/fstab`.

In there you should find a line about `/mnt/usb-ZTE_USB_Storage_FFF1-0:0`:

- remove it
- power off
- remove the USB key you used for the live ubuntu session
- boot your machine.

That's it.